# no such file or directory 'authorized_keys'

Tags: directory

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/dhruvhadoop1/.ssh/id_rsa): cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/ .ssh/authorized_keys
open cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/ .ssh/authorized_keys failed: No such file or directory.
Saving the key failed: cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/ .ssh/authorized_keys.
$ chmod 600 authorized_keys
chmod: cannot access ‘authorized_keys’: No such file or directory
$ chmod 600 authorized_keys
chmod: cannot access ‘authorized_keys’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `ls -la /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys/authorized_keys`

Comment: And stop asking duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

This was the prompt

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/dhruvhadoop1/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

and you have not answered with a file path.

Therefore start the generation again via

```
su - hadoopuser
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

and use the default value or another filename but not a command like `cat ...`, e.g.

```
/home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

After that

```
cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | sudo tee -a /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 600 /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys/authorized_keys
```

Comment: dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$ cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
bash: /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$ cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/ .ssh/authorized_keys
bash: /home/hadoopuser/: Is a directory
dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$ cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
bash: /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$

Comment: How to resolve this error?

Comment: As I said, generate the key again.

Comment: i want to execute this command ...

Comment: $ su - hadoopuser  $ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
  cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh /id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys $ chmod 600 authorized_keys

Comment: Nice, problem solved.

Comment: Please use the check mark at the left side of the answer to accept the answer.

Comment: No , problem is not solved.

Comment: I want to execute the command that i had mentioned..Please help me in getting through.

Comment: Ok start again and use exactly each step in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, answer corrected, start again please.

Comment: @A.B., congratulations on your persistence.